# How CompareTo method logic works in List sort function?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, icomparable

How CompareTo method logic works in List sort function.

```
public class person : IComparable
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        person otherPerson = (person)obj;
        if (this.lastName != otherPerson.lastName)
            return this.lastName.CompareTo(otherPerson.lastName);
        else
            return this.firstName.CompareTo(otherPerson.firstName);
    }

    public person(string _firstName, string _lastName)
    {
        firstName = _firstName;
        lastName = _lastName;
    }

    override public string ToString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}

List<person> l = new List<person>();
l.Add(new person("Mark", "Hanson"));
l.Add(new person("Kim", "Akers"));
l.Add(new person("Zsolt", "Ambrus"));

l.Sort();

foreach (person p in l)
    Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke the [Sort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) on a generic list (List in your case), behind the scenes, the implementation of Sort will check if the type of the list (the `person` class) implements the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface, and if it does it will invoke the [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) member to perform comparisons between elements of the list to perform the sort. The fact that the `person` class implements IComparable is interpreted as a "contract" that specifies that the `person` class will have a method called CompareTo.

The implementation of Sort can use a snippet such as the following to compare to elements of the list:

```
T aPerson;
T anotherPerson;
int compareResult;

if(aPerson is IComparable)
{
    compareResult = (aPerson as IComparable).CompareTo(anotherPerson);
}
```

The CompareTo method always compares the object it is invoked on to the parameter and the meaning of the return value is always the same:

```
* if the two objects are "equal", it returns 0
* if the object you are comparing to is "less than" - in a sorted list it goes before - the object you are invoking CompareTo on, it returns -1
* if the object you are comparing to is "greater than" - in a sorted list it goes after - the object you are invoking CompareTo on, it returns +1
```

Internally, the Sort method uses an optimized QuickSort to actually perform the sort but to make it easier to follow, here's an example of implementing [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which illustrates what happens behind the scenes in terms of invoking the IComparable interface:

```
// assume the Sort invokes this naive bubble sort 
// on the internal backing array of the list
void InternalBubbleSort(T[] backingArray) 
{
  var swapped = false;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < Length - 1; i++) {
      if (backingArray[i].CompareTo(backingArray[i+1]) > 0) {
        T temp = backingArray[i];
        backingArray[i] = backingArray[i+1];
        backingArray[i+1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }while(swapped);
}
```

Comment: it is hard to understand compareTo processing.

Comment: what do you mean by compareTo processing?

Comment: Ok I got your bubblesort example, and I mean same processing which you wrote in your answer. thank you.

Comment: Just for the record, `List<T>.Sort` is documented as using an unstable QuickSort: See the Remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx

Comment: Thanks @LukeH for pointing that out. I considered the actual implementation not important for the purpose of the discussion - regardless of the algorithm they all get down to comparisons between elements. I chose BubbleSort as an example because it is really easy to follow..

Comment: There's always a problem with using bubble-sort in an example; someone might actually use the code! It's always worth adding a caveat when you use it as an example.

Comment: Your bubbleSort example is certainly not easy to follow,  is this supposed to be C#? what language is that? The OP posted in C#. And unfortunately because of the way you worded things, aside from your first paragraph (which is great), I had to mark you down. I had a hell of a time following through the rest of it.

Comment: Hi @ganjeii - thanks for the feedback; I've updated the answer which hopefully clarifies things a bit (the earlier version was just showing a pseudo-code implementation of bubble sort)

Comment: @MikeDinescu ahhh much better!

Answer (score 2):

It sorts by last name, then first name.

If two people have the same last name, the `if` statement will end up comparing by first name.
Otherwise, it will compare by last name.